# How to change menu item spacing in Firefox Proton

Tags: css, firefox

Firefox Proton increased the menu item spacing to levels that displease me. I heard this kind of problem can often be solved by modifying CSSes internal to Firefox. Which CSS should I change, and how, to reduce the spacing between menu items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

about:config toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets true

Create folder and file C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXX.default-release\chrome\userChrome.css and copy the following lines at the top. Restart Firefox. If it doesn't work, delete all the lines in the file and leave only these:

```
/* Bookmark and context menu spacing */
menupopup > menuitem, menupopup > menu {padding-block: 0px !important;}
/* Options menu spacing */
:root {--arrowpanel-menuitem-padding: 0px 0px !important;}
/* Disable rounded tabs */
.tab-background{border-radius: 0px 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important;}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much! This had been, to me, Proton's worst misfeature so far, and this edit made it bearable.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough rep to comment on wyxchari answer, but the added info is worthwhile.
Added this to the bottom of my userChrome.css.  It had no effect.  Added it at the top and it worked and the other changes I had made (tabs on bottom) also worked.  Thanks much

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 92.0 changes the spacing of bookmarks again !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

To fix it you have to add something new to the userChrome.css explained in the previous messages. I put it complete:

```
/* Bookmark and context menu spacing */
menupopup > menuitem, menupopup > menu {padding-block: 0px !important; min-height: 0px !important;}
/* Options menu spacing */
:root {--arrowpanel-menuitem-padding: 0px 0px !important;}
/* Disable rounded tabs */
.tab-background{border-radius: 0px 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best setting.

```
/* Bookmark and context menu spacing */
menupopup > menuitem, menupopup > menu {padding-block: 4px !important; min-height: 0px !important;}
/* Options menu spacing */
:root {--arrowpanel-menuitem-padding: 8px 8px !important;}
/* Disable rounded tabs */
.tab-background{border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px !important; margin-bottom: 2px !important;}
```

Comment: It would be better if you explained it.

Comment: @wyxchari explained above how to change menu item spacing and provided the code. I just changed the values that looks me better and shared here.